# Ubuntu 20.04 after installation on Disk Capacity as Unknown

Tags: gnome, 20.04

After Ubuntu 20.04 installation, GNOME Desktop Setting shown as "Unknown" under

```
GNOME Desktop Setting -->About --> Disk Capacity --> Unknown
```

Refer to the screenshot

[image]

```
Device Name - akromi
Memory - 4 GB
Processor - Intel Ato x5-z8350 CPU @ 1.44 GHz x 4
Graphics - Intel HD Graphics (CHV)
Disk Capacity - Unknown
OS Name - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
OS Type 64-bit
GNOME Version 3.36.1
Widowing System X11
Software Updates

uname -a
Linux akromi 5.4.0-28-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 22 17:40:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Lenovo Miix 320-10ICR - Type 80XF

Please advise for resolving this issue.

Comment: Do other apps such as the file manager and "Gnome Disks" detect the capacity fine?

Comment: Yes, it detects the capacity. How these can be detected?

Comment: https://launchpadlibrarian.net/478494624/GNOME%20Disk.png